# GWT Mouse Movement

Tags: gwt, canvas, mouse

I am trying to draw a string at a specific point based on the mouse position (only when I am dragging).

The problem is, that it seems to scale the x and y.  When I am at 0,0 with the mouse, the string displays in the right spot, but as I move away, the string draws farther and farther away from my mouse which makes me think there is a hidden scaling thing going on...

I am using event.getX() and the position of the canvas, should I be using some other combination to get the correct mouse position?

below is the code

```
        final Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
        final AsyncBool mouseDown = new AsyncBool(false);

        final Context2d context = canvas.getContext2d();
        context.setFont("bold 8px sans-serif"); 

        canvas.setWidth("100%");
        canvas.setHeight("100%");

        canvas.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event)
            {
                if(mouseDown.getBool())
                {

                    context.fillText("Bored.", event.getX() - canvas.getAbsoluteLeft(), event.getY() - canvas.getAbsoluteTop());
                }

            }
        });
        canvas.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event)
            {
                mouseDown.setBool(true);
            }
        });
        canvas.addMouseUpHandler(new MouseUpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEvent event)
            {
                mouseDown.setBool(false);
            }
        });



        RootPanel.get().add(canvas);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work for a canvas which is not resized. But if you resize your canvas, you need to update the canvas coordinate space accordingly as well. For instance, for a 500px, 500px size canvas you can achieve this by :

```
canvas.setSize("500px","500px");
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(500);
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(500);
```

in your case, you size your canvas using percentage values, you can use :

```
canvas.setSize("100%","100%");
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(Window.getClientHeight()); 
canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(Window.getClientWidth());
```

since these methods don't accept percentage values, you need to calculate the parent container's width, and height in pixels.